# Separating out the standard functions in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, schema, functions

I’ve been using PostgreSQL for many years, and, among other things, I have added a number of my own user defined scalar functions.

Of course, if I knew about it at the time, I should have added my own functions to a separate schema for better management. Instead, my functions are all mixed in with the standard ones.

Is there a way of distinguishing the standard functions so that I can better organise my own functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; look at the schema that contains them. If it is `pg_catalog`, that is a system function. If not, it is a user defined function.

A grey area are functions that belong to an extension. You can only identify them by their membership in an extension. One simple way is to run a `pg_dump -s`: functions that belong to extension won't be included in that.

Alternatively, here is a query that will list all functions that don't belong t the PostgreSQL system or an extension:

```
BEGIN;  /* for SET LOCAL */

SET LOCAL search_path = '';  /* show all schemas */

SELECT f.oid::regprocedure
FROM pg_proc AS f
WHERE f.pronamespace NOT IN ('pg_catalog'::regnamespace,
                             'information_schema'::regnamespace)
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM pg_depend AS d
                  WHERE d.objid = f.oid AND d.deptype = 'e');

COMMIT;  /* reset "search_path" */
```

Best practice is to define a schema for the database objects you create yourself. Then create all extensions in the `public` schema, so that their functions end up there. Don't forget to `REVOKE` the `CREATE` privilege on the `public` schema (if you are using v14 or lower).

Comment: OK, I’ve looked in `pg_catalog` and found a ship load of functions. However in the `public` schema, for example, I can see some of my own functions, but also functions like `ceiling(numberid)` which I know that I didn’t write. That same function also appears in `pg_catalog` so I don’t know why it’s also in `public'.

Comment: No idea how you created that function, but it is not part of the system. I have added a query that might help you.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. I can see now that `public` shouldn’t have anything to begin with. I created a test database from `template0` and it didn’t have any functions in `public`. That would mean that it’s safe to drop them all and start agin. It also means that I’ve cluttered up my `template` with some junk.